# AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth vs. SizeToFit

Tags: ios, uiview, sizetofit

I'm using `SizeToFit` because I don't have to specify the `Frame` property to have an adaptive size of the `UIButton`/`UILabel`. In my case it's a button on a toolbar. Now I made the following observation:

If I use `AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` together with `SizeToFit` than the font size isn't adapted anymore. So I can

1. Specify a `Frame` and use `AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`
2. Use `SizeToFit` but don't have the adjustable font size anymore

Do you also have this problem? How do you circumvent this problem? How to let the intrinsic content size drive the frame size? Or do I have to set the `Frame` property? The advantage of Autolayout was to not define a frime size any more ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I made an error in reasoning. `SizeToFit` defines the size after the content (content has already a fixed size). `AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` needs a frame in which it can change the font size. Both together doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro I've made to address this issue so that you can shrink font size to fit width AND call sizeToFit without the font size going back up post-shrink.

```
///Works like `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` but allows you to use `sizeToFit` and/or measure the new [adjusted] font size; one time adjustment, needs to be called again if `.text` changes.
#define shrinkFontSizeIfNeeded(__label) {\
UIFont *__currentFont = __label.font;\
CGFloat __originalFontSize = __currentFont.pointSize;\
CGSize __currentSize = [__label.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : __currentFont}];\
while (__currentSize.width > __label.frame.size.width && __currentFont.pointSize > (__originalFontSize * __label.minimumScaleFactor)) {\
    __currentFont = [__currentFont fontWithSize:__currentFont.pointSize - 1];\
    __currentSize = [__label.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : __currentFont}];\
}\
__label.font = __currentFont;\
}
```