# Dynamically adjust UILabel frame height after dynamically adjusting the internal text size to fit

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am working with an UILabel that is constrained to a fixed width, and no more than a certain height (fixed to, say, half the screen size)

To allow our app to work across iOS devices, I set `adjustsfontsizetofitwidth` to be true on the UILabel. This leads to a resulting adjustment of the font size of the text if the screen size is small.

However, it appears that if the font is actually resized, the UILabel now has extra top and bottom padding to the text. This is marked as part of its intrinsic content size.

This extra vertical padding is problematic, because I have a button that needs to sit right below the baseline of the last line of text.

I need a method to now readjust my frame to tightly fit the newly adjusted text size.

I tried using `sizeToFit()` as well as `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` in `layoutSubviews()` for my view class, but to no avail.

It seems similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326688/autolayout-causing-uilabel-to-resize-with-unwanted-padding) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019181/adjustsfontsizetofitwidth-vs-sizetofit), neither of which have answers that work for me.

```swift
class ProblemExample: UIViewController {
     private let instructionsLabel: UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel().disableAutoresizingMask()
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut adhuc argumentum vix, vix eruditi appetere corrumpit in. Quod cibo mnesarchum ex sea. Ad qui case assum delicata, ei laudem prodesset democritum per, alia admodum efficiantur has id. Semper integre ei est, quo dolor causae definitionem ei. Malis impedit vim at, vero quas sit ea. Quaeque expetenda an est."
            label.font = Theme.headingFont // BIG FONT
            label.setLineSpacing(multiple: 1.15)
            label.textColor = .black
            label.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
            label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
            label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5

            return label
        }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.addSubview(instructionsLabel)
        // Using https://github.com/roberthein/TinyConstraints for syntactical lightness
        instructionsLabel.widthToSuperview(multiplier:0.5)
        instructionsLabel.heightToSuperview(multiplier:0.5, relation:.equalOrLess)
        instructionsLabel.centerYToSuperview()

        button = UIButton()
        self.addSubView()
        button.bottom(to: instructionsLabel)
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need dynamic height then dont use this constraint heightToSuperview..... just use left, right, bottom , top constraint you may use width constraint but not height.

Comment: @Winston try "label.lineBreakMode = .wordWrap" then it'll increase the height.
Considering you've given all the proper constraints (top, leading, training, bottom) and keeping in mind that top and bottom constraints are not of fix value.

Comment: My method to calculate the height of UILabel,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45182097/419348

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I meant heightToSuperview as an less than or equal to constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can profit from the built-in behavior when you need either to fit text into the frame, or stretch frame according to the text size. It seems to me, you need both. Hence you have to do it yourself.

The approximate flow would be the following:

- get the text that you are going to assign to the label
- calculate the text's height knowing its width ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30450434/figure-out-size-of-uilabel-based-on-string-in-swift))
- if text height is more than max label height, set label to max height, otherwise set it to text height
- assign text to label

Comment: Thank you for addressing my initial question.
I'm still having trouble understanding the implementation of this behavior: at what stage will I know the width if it is calculated by auto layout?

Comment: After `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` has been called, you can calculate the width (e.g. superview.width - label.leading - label.trailing, or whatever your formula is).

Comment: So you mean in the definition for overriding `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`?

Comment: You can do these steps in viewDidLayoutSubviews() or at any time after it's called. You also need to have the text, don't you? (I don't know if it comes from backend or somewhere else...)

Comment: it seems strange to be manually inputting the formula calculating the width, when I should just get it from auto layout.

To clarify, I tried your solution, but even at the time `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, I still don't have the real width.

I don't understand how the property `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` does this rescaling under the hood. If I had that code, I should be able to solve this problem.

Comment: If you don’t have the width in viewDidLayoutSubviews, most probably something affects it later.

Comment: I do have the width of my UILabel in viewDidLayoutSubviews. The problem is that in my case I don't have it on the initial call of viewDidLayoutSubviews. This is because the method is called every time a subview is added to the view. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728372/when-is-layoutsubviews-called). Thus, imagine in my example my UILabel had its width also constrained by another object in the hierarchy before all of my subviews even exist to calculate the actual width constraint on my UILabel, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` gets called.

Comment: Ok, but then you can calculate the width yourself. Just do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using following code, always add runtime rendering in `viewDidLayoutSubViews` or after `viewDidLayoutSubViews`

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

 override func viewDidLayoutSubViews(){
        super.viewDidLayoutSubViews()
        self.addSubview(instructionsLabel)
        // Using https://github.com/roberthein/TinyConstraints for syntactical lightness
        instructionsLabel.widthToSuperview(multiplier:0.5)
        instructionsLabel.heightToSuperview(multiplier:0.5, relation:.equalOrLess)
        instructionsLabel.centerYToSuperview()
        if button == nil {
            button = UIButton()
            self.addSubView()
            button.bottom(to: instructionsLabel)
        }
}
```

Comment: This is overly hacky. There is only one additional layer of dependency expression.

What if you are doing dynamic constraints on dynamic constraints?

Comment: to handle this we used nil to it will not enter in if conditions, after first initialization . and for label it is already lazy.